# Django API: grabing Nested Json for UnitTest

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have api end point and trouble in garbing item from nested json...

I am writing test like this and printing what data it me appears:

```py
    class TestSingleArticle(TestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            article = ArticleFactory2.create()
            self.url = reverse('article-single2', args=[article.alias])

        def test_single_article_get(self):
            request = self.client.get(self.url)
            print(request.data)
```

When I run this, I see following json in `terminal`

```
{
 'alias': '508674f2-b570-47f1-b1d8-01592a3af359', 
 'author': OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('organization', OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('organization_name', 'org name'), ('contact', '256644')])), ('name', 'jhon doe'), ('detail', 'this is detail')]), 
 'category': OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('name', 'sci-fi')]), 
 'title': 'i am title', 
 'body': 'i am body'
}
```

I am trying grab `contact` from above `json` but i failed....

---

**If you don't understand above statement, see these optional hint for you.**

This is my serialization class:

```py
    from rest_framework import serializes
    from . models import Author, Article, Category, Organization


    class OrganizationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Organization
            fields = '__all__'


    class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        organization = OrganizationSerializer():
        class Meta:
            model = Author
            fields = '__all__'


    class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Category
            fields = '__all__'


    class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        author = AuthorSerializer()
        category = CategorySerializer()
        class Meta:
            model =  Article
            fields = '__all__'
```

and below are my models:

```py
    from django.db import models
    import uuid

    class Organization(models.Model):
        organization_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        contact = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.organization_name

    class Author(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
        detail = models.TextField()
        organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class Article(models.Model):
        alias = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
        author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author')
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        body = models.TextField()
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Anyways, I want to grab `contact` from the nested json, can anyone help me in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you may specify a `format` in your `self.client.get` function call and set it as JSON:

```
request = self.client.get(self.url, format='json')
```

Afterwards you can simply fetch your contact like this:

```
contact = request.data['author']['organization']['contact']
```

Comment: @mamuncode Can you provide a stacktrace of the error you receive?

Comment: print(request.data['author']['contact'])
KeyError: 'contact'

Comment: not works yet, i am not getting whats wrong with it

Comment: @mamuncode It was my mistake in the answer. I haven't noticed your hierarchy and that your `contact` field is in your `Organization` model, not in the `Author`. Now it should work as expected.

Comment: oh, thanks for your time, it works now... thanks again, you made my day